# :: notation for one time binding is not working on AnguarJS 1.6.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are using AngularJS 1.6.4 for one of our application which needs to show thousands of rows in a list on a single page. But for 7K entries the page is getting hang. So, we have decided to use one time binding for those pages. Unfortunately the `::` notation is not working which it should be.

There was a list html fragment like:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

We have changed it to:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{ ::item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

But it is not working.

Any idea if it is removed on version 1.6.4?
More info: http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-ngrepeat-performance-watchers/

Comment: <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ ::item.name }}</li> this is the correct one

Comment: <li ng-repeat="item in items>{{::item.name}}</li> should work, however I see your motive is to bind data in view not two-directional flow so you can use ng-bind as well.

Comment: Of course, it is working. Why you think it is not? 7k rows may kill your browser without any javascript.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov You are wrong. 43K rows of HTML & CSS works fine in PgAdmin 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. The problem is when the list was rendering the variable was empty `[]`, after a success AJAX call we assigned the data to the list. So, angular was binding to the initial empty `[]` list.

Comment: You are right. It is supossed that angular set watchers in the following way:
1. **Two-way-binding** listener for change on input and the value on $scope like when using an ng-model on an input. 

2. **one-way-bindind** `{{ }}` That element will be assigned with a watcher as well, so that means a direct update in controller is automatically updated in UI.
3. **One time binding**. when the variable has a value a watcher will be assigned, then shown on the UI and unassigned after rendered. So any change after that won´t have effect. Hope This piece of theory help others understand why.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps a lot to understand the angular binding.